# How to work with ESP13 wifi shield for arduino?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I recently bought a ESP13 wifi shield which has to mount on to Arduino. I think it is much similar to esp8266 modules, but unable to find a proper guidelines/libraries relevant to it. I did not notice any helpful tutorials also. Here, I want to use this module to run as a wifi server.

Answer (score 0):

An ESP13 is an ESP8266.  It is version ESP-13.

It is not a WiFi shield for Arduino; although you can connect it to an Arduino via serial pins and use its WiFi capabilities.

The ESP8266 ESP-13 is a stand alone device.  It combines a processor with WiFi so you don't need an Arduino for simple jobs (or not that simple; I use mine to receive REST commands and run 60 addressable LEDs in pretty patterns).

There are lots of resources for ESP8266s:
For example: https://tuts.codingo.me/introduction-to-esp8266-module.

Note that the pin locations change between versions so look out for that when making circuits.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I'm talking about a Arduino shield. Refer below link.
http://www.robotistan.com/esp8266-esp-12e-wifi-arduino-shield

Comment: Oh, they named the board the same as the chip!
A quick search shows a lot of people have problems with this board.
The only suggestion I can see is to swap the Rx/Tx pins.
See: http://community.blynk.cc/t/getting-started-with-esp-13-sheild-esp8266/6704/10